# how to check if contenteditable div contains only empty elements or elements with only whitespace

Tags: jquery

How do I check if a contenteditable div contains only empty elements or elements with whitespaces only as shown in the html code below.

```
<div contenteditable='true'>
     <!--All these elements below would be invisible to the human eye-->
    <p></p>
    <p> &nbsp </p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>          </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the count of non-empty child nodes

```js
console.log(
  $('div[contenteditable]') // get contenteditable div
  .contents() // get child nodes
  .filter(function() { // filter nodes
    return this.nodeType !== 8 && // avoid comment node
      this.textContent.trim().length // check content length
  }).length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable='true'>
  <!--All these elements below would be invisible to the human eye-->
  <p></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

---

Or simply using **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** and **[`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** (or native javascript **[`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)** method) get the trimmed text content and check it's length.

```js
console.log(
  $.trim($('div[contenteditable]') // get contenteditable div
    .text()).length
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable='true'>
  <!--All these elements below would be invisible to the human eye-->
  <p></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` `$.trim()` to remove white-spaces from `div` or `container`, then use `.text()` to `get text(s) inside container`, after you use `jQuery` `$.length()` to `count` how much `character(s)` inside `each container`, check with `console` or `alert` or `if else` condition the length grater then zero.

here is small peace of code to check white-space(s)

**jQuery Code**:

```
$('div[contenteditable]>p').each(function(){
  var lengthCheck = $(this).text().trim().length;
  alert(lengthCheck);
});
```